# Getting a green screen when encoding and then decoding vp8 streamed video

Tags: c++, encoding, decoding, libvpx, libyuv

I am trying to add vp8 encoding and decoding to my streaming project. I am reading in color frames from OpenNI into a color frame buffer using the `openni::PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB888` format. Then I am trying to compress each RGB888 frame using vp8 and streaming it over UDP to my viewer. The viewer uncompresses the frame into RGB and then displays it. I can get the end-to-end functionality working properly with JPEG compression but when I try to implement compression with the VP8 codec, I get a mostly green frame with small blocks of white towards the top.

I'm using libyuv to convert RGB to and from yv12. 
My VP8 encoding code is:

```
#define VPX_CODEC_DISABLE_COMPAT 1
#include "vpx/vpx_encoder.h"
#include "vpx/vp8cx.h"
#define VPX_INTERFACE (vpx_codec_vp8_cx())

// Code from http://www.webmproject.org/docs/vp8-sdk/example__simple__encoder.html
void vp8::init(const QUALITY quality)
{
    m_quality = vpx_quality_convert(quality);

    // INFO("VPX interface: %s", vpx_codec_iface_name(VPX_INTERFACE));

    const vpx_codec_iface_t* iface = VPX_INTERFACE;
    ASSERT(iface);

    vpx_codec_enc_cfg_t config;
    vpx_codec_err_t res = vpx_codec_enc_config_default(iface, &config, 0);
    ASSERT_THROW(res == VPX_CODEC_OK, "failed to get config: %s", vpx_codec_err_to_string(res));

    // Adjust default target bit-rate to account for actual desktop size.
    config.rc_target_bitrate = width() * height() *
      config.rc_target_bitrate / config.g_w / config.g_h;

    config.g_w = width();
    config.g_h = height();

    m_vpx_codec = new vpx_codec_ctx_t;

    res = vpx_codec_enc_init(m_vpx_codec, iface, &config, 0);
    if (res)
    {
        delete m_vpx_codec;
        m_vpx_codec = nullptr;
        THROW("failed initialize codec: %s", vpx_codec_err_to_string(res)); 
    }
}

vp8::~vp8()
{
    if (m_vpx_codec)
    {   
        vpx_codec_err_t  res = vpx_codec_destroy(m_vpx_codec);
        VPX_CODEC_THROW(m_vpx_codec, res, "error destroying vpx codec");
    }
    delete m_vpx_codec;
}

size_t convert_to_yv12(uint8_t* output, const uint8_t* input)
{
    // YV12 is the same as i420 but with the U and V planes switched
    uint8_t* y_plane = output;
    uint8_t* v_plane = output + num_frame_pixels() * 1;
    uint8_t* u_plane = output + num_frame_pixels() * 5 / 4;

    // Do the conversion here
    switch (input_format())
    {
    case STREAM_FORMAT::COLOR_RGB888:
        // YV12 is the same as i420 except with the u and v planes switched
        libyuv::RAWToI420(input, width() * sizeof(RGB888Pixel),
                          y_plane, width(),
                          u_plane, width() / 2,
                          v_plane, width() / 2,
                          width(), height() );
        break;
    default:
        THROW("can't convert format %1%", input_format());
        break;
    }

    return num_frame_pixels() * 3 / 2;
}

size_t vp8::encode(uint8_t* output, const uint8_t* input, const size_t output_buffer_size, const size_t input_buffer_size)
{
    convert_to_yv12(m_work_buf, input);

    // Encode the frame
    vpx_image_t img_wrapper;
    vpx_img_wrap(&img_wrapper, VPX_IMG_FMT_YV12, width(), height(), 1, m_work_buf);

    vpx_codec_err_t res = vpx_codec_encode(m_vpx_codec, &img_wrapper, m_encoder_count, 1, 
                                           0, VPX_DL_REALTIME); // quality());
    VPX_CODEC_THROW(m_vpx_codec, res, "write_frames: failed to encode frame");

    vpx_codec_iter_t iter = nullptr;
    const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt;

    size_t bytes_written = 0;

    while ( (pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(m_vpx_codec, &iter)) )
    {
        switch (pkt->kind)
        {
        case VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT:
            ASSERT(bytes_written + pkt->data.frame.sz <= output_buffer_size);

            memcpy(output, pkt->data.frame.buf, pkt->data.frame.sz);

            output += pkt->data.frame.sz;
            bytes_written += pkt->data.frame.sz;
            break;
        default: // ignore everything else
            break;
        }
    }

    ASSERT(vpx_codec_get_cx_data(m_vpx_codec, &iter) == nullptr);

    m_encoder_count++;

    return bytes_written;
}
```

My VP8 decoding code is:

```
#define VPX_CODEC_DISABLE_COMPAT 1
#include "vpx/vpx_decoder.h"
#include "vpx/vp8dx.h"
#define VPX_INTERFACE (vpx_codec_vp8_dx())

// Code from http://www.webmproject.org/docs/vp8-sdk/example__simple__decoder.html
vp8::vp8()
{
    // INFO("VPX interface: %s", vpx_codec_iface_name(VPX_INTERFACE));

    m_vpx_codec = new vpx_codec_ctx_t;

    vpx_codec_err_t  res = vpx_codec_dec_init(m_vpx_codec, VPX_INTERFACE, nullptr, 0);
    VPX_CODEC_THROW(m_vpx_codec, res, "failed to initialize the codec");
}

vp8::~vp8()
{
    if (m_vpx_codec)
    {   
        vpx_codec_err_t  res = vpx_codec_destroy(m_vpx_codec);
        VPX_CODEC_THROW(m_vpx_codec, res, "error destroying vpx codec");
    }
    delete m_vpx_codec;
}

void vp8::decode(RGB888Pixel* output, 
                 const uint8_t* input, 
                 const size_t /* output_buffer_size_in_bytes */, 
                 const size_t input_buffer_size_in_bytes)
{
    vpx_codec_err_t res = vpx_codec_decode(m_vpx_codec, input, input_buffer_size_in_bytes, nullptr, 0);
    VPX_CODEC_THROW(m_vpx_codec, res, "error decoding frame");

    // Get a YV12 image frame from the decoder
    vpx_codec_iter_t  iter = NULL;
    vpx_image_t      *img;

    img = vpx_codec_get_frame(m_vpx_codec, &iter);

    ASSERT(vpx_codec_get_frame(m_vpx_codec, &iter) == nullptr);

    ASSERT_EQUAL(img->d_w, width());
    ASSERT_EQUAL(img->d_h, height());

    const uint8_t* y_plane = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_Y];
    const uint8_t* u_plane = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_U];
    const uint8_t* v_plane = img->planes[VPX_PLANE_V];

    int ret =
    libyuv::I420ToRAW(y_plane, img->stride[VPX_PLANE_Y],
                      u_plane, img->stride[VPX_PLANE_U],
                      v_plane, img->stride[VPX_PLANE_V],
                      (uint8*)output, stride_in_bytes(STREAM_FORMAT::COLOR_RGB888, output_stride_in_pixels()),
                      width(), height() );
    ASSERT(ret == 0);

}
```

Basically, I copied all of the code from VP8's simple encoder and decoder examples. But I can't figure out which of my assumtions are wrong. (Also, I'm struggling because there are no examples of using libyuv with libvpx together which is weird because both are developed by Google)

Thanks!
@bensch128

Comment: I solved it myself. I hadn't initialized m_work_buf.         
vpx_img_wrap() doesn't return an error when the data buffer is nullptr.      
Go figure...

Comment: I am getting a green screen as well, I am building a screen recorder. do think this is the place I should look into `while( (pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(&codec, &iter)) ) {
   switch(pkt->kind) {
    case VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT:
     //store the packet im queue

     glb_app_thread.message_loop().PostWork(callback_factory_.NewCallback(&EncoderInstance::write_ivf_frame_header, pkt));
     glb_app_thread.message_loop().PostWork(callback_factory_.NewCallback(&EncoderInstance::WriteFile, pkt));
     break;
    default:break;
   }`